# Why identity and const are placed in different modules in scala-library?

Tags: scala, identity

Seems to be a minor issue, but for me it's some kind of POLA violation. Is there any reason to have identity and const (which better rename to "constantly") in different modules?

I found that const was added to the scala.Function object by Martin Odersky in 2008. Identity was an implicit inside scala.Predef in those days, and became just a function after 'conforms' and '<:<' was introduced. So it seems that identity as "type checker" was actually deprecated.

Identity and const have strong semantical relation to each other. The only difference i can see is that 'const' is curried - but both used as functional forms: List(1,2,3).map(identity); List(1,2,3).map(constantly(5))

Comment: What package is `const` in? I've wanted something like that in the past, but didn't know it was in the standard library.

Comment: Wow, cool. I've typically gotten that effect by doing `List(1,2,3).map(_ => 5)`, which is more concise, I guess, but `List(1,2,3).map(constantly(5))` feels more correct.

Comment: you can use x => x instead of identity. it's question of what do you prefer: symbols or words. it's a good practice to have both options in the library (like in scalaz)

Comment: Being discussed rightn now on the scala-language list, at lengthm as you know. Historical reasons.

Comment: link to the discussion - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/IgMLwK3ztjk